# What iText object should I use to describe HTML Div alike object

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

I have a 2x3 PdfpTable, I want to have multiple boxes, like HTML Div, in each PdfpCell, I will also want to define the starting position, weight, height, h-alignment, v-alignment, border for each box. What itext object should I use for my boxes in PdfpCell? I have tried PdfDiv, but i am not able to define the h-alignment, v-alignment or the starting position for PdfDiv.

Thanks.

Comment: You can nest PdfPTables in other PdfPTables. Have you tried doing that? If that's not what you want, are you working with predefined heights/widths for the cells?

Comment: I'd ignore `PdfPTable` completely if you want to position things absolutely. Instead, a `ColumnText` should do almost everything that you're looking for except perhaps borders. However, if you've got absolute positions and dimensions you can then just draw a rectangle at those positions after you draw the text. That's essentially what a `PdfPTable` does behind the scenes, too.